# Find two distinct numbers in a set in O(n log n) time so that their difference is the smallest of all pairs

Tags: algorithm, set

How do I find two distinct numbers a and b in a unsorted set S in O(n log n) time so that |a-b| is the smallest among all possible pairs?

Answer (score 1):

First, sort the list using, say, quicksort, which is O(n log n).

Then do a single pass through the list, measuring the interval between each number and the following number, and keeping track of the smallest interval you've seen. That's O(n).

O(n) + O(n log n) = O(n log n)

Comment: Not need to sort. But if you do, just return the first and last element of the array no need to go through the array.